# Lynn: Light Armor or Heavy Armor?

Tags: vindictus

Should I go with light armor or heavy armor for Lynn? I've read that late game, heavy armor tends to benefit more since it saves you from dying quickly. But that forum post was pertaining to Lann. I feel that light armor would also work with Lynn because of her hit-and-run playstyle, being able to quickly move from harm.

**Which is better for Lynn?**

Comment: So what was your route?

Answer (score 1):

Right now Lynn is my highest level character and one of my favorites. I recommend using light armor instead of heavy armor because as you must know Lynn is a hit and run character and you need the speed. Even if you have your heavy armor maxed out it would still not help you with speed. If you absolutely want heavy armor then I recommend having all light armor except either torso or leg armor. Plate armor is not that bad either but don't go overboard but it does look sucky. 
Hope this helps...